# Webpack: use AMD library from class module

Tags: webpack, amd

I'm writing a browser app. I have a small ES6 module that is one class (not asynchronous) that wants to use the [pluralize library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pluralize).

I don't understand how my class methods can use the pluralize lib.

I tried

```
// my lib module
define(function (require, exports, module) {
    const pluralize = require('pluralize');

    class JsonToSdk {
        ...
    }

    return JsonToSdk;
});   

// my calling module
import {JsonToSdk} from './libfile';
jsonToSdk = new JsonToSdk()
```

**But** received error: JsonToSdk is not a constructor

The [webpack docs for AMD modules](https://webpack.js.org/api/module-methods/#amd) give an example of

```
define(['jquery', 'my-module'], function($, myModule) {
    // Do something with $ and myModule...

    // Export a function
    return function doSomething() {
        // ...
    };
});
```

but I don't understand where I would define the content of myModule, its class, and export statement.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I switched to just using a straight import statement in the class module and it's working.

I'm using:

```
import pluralize from "pluralize/pluralize"; // The AMD library

class JsonToSdk {
    ... methods can use the pluralize library
}
export { JsonToSdk }
```